# Creating a "read more" link that extends the content on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a read more link that would extend a paragraph already being shown to reveal the entire text on the same page. If this could be solves with HTML5 and CSS, I would like that, but I assume some type of script will be needed.

For example:

### Example text

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porttitor feugiat ipsum quis ullamcorper. Nullam vitae velit vitae tortor semper tempor ac vitae magna. Maecenas a ullamcorper neque. Aliquam vitae tortor luctus nisi rutrum eleifend non non leo.

**Sed eleifend lectus id semper accumsan. Sed lobortis id ligula eget blandit. Integer interdum iaculis nunc, sed porttitor magna tincidunt in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam lobortis accumsan tempor. Aliquam sollicitudin pulvinar est, quis convallis tellus.**

Read More >>

I would like the normal text to be shown with the "Read More >>" link below, and then the bold text will be revealed after clicking the link.

I also want to have an image in the hidden section, would this be possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything on it because I don't know what it would be called. If I had a word to go on from the code, I would be able to locate a solution I think. I looked at OnClick and Includes, but so far. Even the name of a site that uses it would be helpful for the source inspect.

Comment: You can solve this with HTML5 =JavaScript and more new html features, but you may need to do some research on  dynamic web pages and JavaScript to get a better understanding of how to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will look around for the best solution, and try the answers below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A vanilla JS alternative:

The HTML:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porttitor feugiat ipsum quis ullamcorper. Nullam vitae velit vitae tortor semper tempor ac vitae magna. Maecenas a ullamcorper neque. Aliquam vitae tortor luctus nisi rutrum eleifend non non leo.</p>
<div id="more" style="display:none;">
    <p>Sed eleifend lectus id semper accumsan. Sed lobortis id ligula eget blandit. Integer interdum iaculis nunc, sed porttitor magna tincidunt in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam lobortis accumsan tempor. Aliquam sollicitudin pulvinar est, quis convallis tellus.</p>
    <img..../>
</div>
<a href="javascript:showMore()" id="link">Read More >></a>`
```

The JS:

```js
function showMore(){
    //removes the link
    document.getElementById('link').parentElement.removeChild('link');
    //shows the #more
    document.getElementById('more').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Why not add a class to the element and let css do the styling?

Comment: That works just as well, but I just wanted to keep the code block count at 2. :P @Sean

Answer (score 5):

There is some really grateful plugins out there uses jquery.
Here is what i found

https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js

The required markup for Readmore.js is also extremely lightweight and very simple. No need for complicated sets of  div s or hardcoded class names, just call  `.readmore()`  on the element containing your block of text and Readmore.js takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 4):

I created something easy to use

- set a class to the content "div"
- use "<!--more-->" to separate the click-to-display contents from the always visible contents
- everything else will be taking care of by css and js

HTML:

```
<div class="m-more-less-content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <!--more--> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
</div>
```

See example [here](https://codepen.io/qiaoli116/pen/MqNObm)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a jQuery/JS script that should do the trick:
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Starfire1337/pL9ve/

HTML:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/site.js"></script> // Notice the custom JS is included AFTER jQuery
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porttitor feugiat ipsum quis ullamcorper. Nullam vitae velit vitae tortor semper tempor ac vitae magna. Maecenas a ullamcorper neque. Aliquam vitae tortor luctus nisi rutrum eleifend non non leo.</p>
<a href="#collapse" class="nav-toggle">Read More...</a>
<div id="collapse" style="display:none">
    <p>Sed eleifend lectus id semper accumsan. Sed lobortis id ligula eget blandit. Integer interdum iaculis nunc, sed porttitor magna tincidunt in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam lobortis accumsan tempor. Aliquam sollicitudin pulvinar est, quis convallis tellus.</p>
</div>
```

and in /js/site.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                toggle_switch.html('Show');
            } else {
                toggle_switch.html('Hide');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this didn't work for me despite the fiddle.

Comment: I might have included an outdated version of jQuery, just update the html until you have the latest version

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, change the property of CSS via Javascript.

```
element.style.display = 'block';
```

**JS code**

```
function read_more() {
document.getElementById('hidden-first').style.display = 'block';
}

document.getElementById('read-more').addEventListener('click', read_more);
```

[See this code on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PBfDa/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is ... this is just a small example http://jsfiddle.net/QDg4P/3/

```
<div>
<h1>Example text</h1>
<p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porttitor feugiat ipsum quis ullamcorper. Nullam vitae velit vitae tortor semper tempor ac vitae magna. Maecenas a ullamcorper neque. Aliquam vitae tortor luctus nisi rutrum eleifend non non leo.</p><a href="#" onclick="show('example1')"> read more </a>
<p id="example1" style="display:none; font-weight: bold"><img src="http://tux.crystalxp.net/png/kami23-flower-tux-4037.png"/>Sed eleifend lectus id semper accumsan. Sed lobortis id ligula eget blandit. Integer interdum iaculis nunc, sed porttitor magna tincidunt in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam lobortis accumsan tempor. Aliquam sollicitudin pulvinar est, quis convallis tellus.</p>

<script>
 function show(ele){
     document.getElementById(ele).style.display = 'block';   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure HTML + CSS solution. You can style the "show more" checkbox using CSS to make it fit your needs, including hiding the checkbox part.

http://jsfiddle.net/T7eXL/

```
<div id="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsummy</p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="show-more"> Show more
    <div class="more">
        <p>Lorem</p>
    </div>
</div>

.more {
    display:none;
}

#box .show-more:checked + .more {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks a bunch. I'll try this out. Also, is there no way to make the input type a link? That would make it a lot easier.

Comment: I assume making it a link in this method is impossible, so how would I hide the checkbox. I can't change the display of all of it to 'none' because it just turns to text.

Answer (score 0):

after text put that code

```
<p><a onclick="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv')">Read more</a></p>
<div class="mid" id="HiddenDiv" style="display: none;">
    <font face="Arial" size="+2" color="#306Eff" align="right">YOUR REST OF THE TEXT HERE YOUR REST OF THE TEXT HERE
 YOUR REST OF THE TEXT HERE YOUR REST OF THE TEXT HERE YOUR REST OF THE TEXT HERE YOUR REST OF THE TEXT HERE YOUR REST OF THE TEXT HERE YOUR REST OF THE TEXT HERE
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function ShowHide(divId)
{
    if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display == 'none')
    {
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this (have read more element after text) and you also have multiple dynamic elements:

> Every month first 10 TB are are not charged. All other traffic... Read more

HTML&CSS:

```
<small class="truncate_string_multilines block-with-text" id="multiline_block" data-initial_value="Every month first 10 TB are are not charged. All other traffic (incoming and outgoing) is charged <a href="" class="morelink_multi">Read more</a>">Every month first 10 TB are are not charged. All other traffic... <a href="#" class="morelink_multi">Read more</a></small> 

.block-with-text {
     height: 4.2em;
}
small {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

JS&JQUERY

```
var initial_string = [], wordArray = '';
function ellipsizeTextBox(class_name) {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName(class_name);
    for (i = 0, len = el.length; i < len; i++) {
        initial_string[i] = el[i].innerHTML;
        wordArray = el[i].innerHTML.split(' ');
        while(el[i].scrollHeight > el[i].offsetHeight) {
            wordArray.pop();
            el[i].innerHTML = wordArray.join(' ') + '... ' + "<a href=\"#\" class=\"morelink_multi\">" + moretext + "</a>";
            }
            el[i].setAttribute("data-initial_value", initial_string[i]);
        }
    }



$("body").on("click",".morelink_multi", function(){
    var this_element = $(this),
        parent_of_link = $(this).parent();
    if(this_element.hasClass("less")) {
        this_element.removeClass("less");
        this_element.html(moretext);
        parent_of_link.addClass('block-with-text');
        ellipsizeTextBox('truncate_string_multilines');
    } else {
        parent_of_link.removeClass('block-with-text');
        parent_of_link.html('');
        parent_of_link.html(parent_of_link.data('initial_value') + " <a href=\"#\" class='morelink_multi less'>"+ lesstext + "</a>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

More advanced version if your text is dynamic or coming from a database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Add Read More Link</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxLength = 300;
    $(".show-read-more").each(function(){
        var myStr = $(this).text();
        if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
            var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
            var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
            $(this).empty().html(newStr);
            $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
            $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
        }
    });
    $(".read-more").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
</script>
<style>
    .show-read-more .more-text{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>    
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p class="show-read-more">This is a very long paragraph...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_expanding_grid.asp

Another Vanilla HTML, javascript and css example if you want something like this, and changes the box on click of Box 2 or Box 3. At this moment in time I have put cross button on the expanded div only but you can put it back on click of the box again :

[image]

HTML :

```
<!-- The grid: three columns -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b1');" style="background: green;">Box 1</div>
    <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b2');" style="background: blue;">Box 2</div>
    <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b3');" style="background: red;">Box 3</div>
</div>

<!-- The expanding grid (hidden by default) -->
<div id="b1" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: green">
    <!-- If you want the ability to close the container, add a close button -->
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">x</span>
    <h2>Box 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
</div>

<div id="b2" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: blue">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">x</span>
    <h2>Box 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
</div>

<div id="b3" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: red">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">x</span>
    <h2>Box 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* The grid: Three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.containerTab {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Closable button inside the image */
.closebtn {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
// Hide all elements with class="containerTab", except for the one that matches the clickable grid column
function openTab(tabName) {
  var i, x;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("containerTab");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following HTML example use read more link

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        #more {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Read More Read Less Button</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi
        lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas
            nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc
            sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed
            ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum.
            Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
            var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
            var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

            if (dots.style.display === "none") {
                dots.style.display = "inline";
                btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
                moreText.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                dots.style.display = "none";
                btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
                moreText.style.display = "inline";
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```